# font-size 0 still shows up in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, font-size

For some odd reason, when I set a font-size:0px; in my style-sheet for an anchor link, IE7 still shows a tiny-tiny version of the text.  Is there anything I should consider doing to completely hide the text, without using text-indent?

The anchor itself is using a background image in the css.  And I simply want to hide the text that in the anchor link, on the HTML page.

Comment: Have you considered changing the line-height to 0 as well?

Comment: Honestly I haven't, but using just visibility:hidden, seems to be a good solution...

Comment: David, your solution works well too.  Thank you for sharing that!

Comment: What's wrong with text-indent?

Comment: My reason for not using text-indent - Several sources on the web and even here on stackoverflow, mention that you can receive a performance hit, depending on how the text-indent box is drawn out.  Even if that never happens to me, I'd rather have my code as healthy as possible without putting myself at risk for sites that I am trying to get ranked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`visibility: hidden` and `display: none` are the standards in hiding elements.

The difference between the two is that `visibility` acts like opacity, in which the element is hidden but it still affects the layout of the page (e.g. a 200px high element will still make the element below it 200px lower than if it were not there).

`display` acts as if the element were not there at all - a 200px high element would not make an element below it 200px lower that it would be if the first element were not there.

**Summary**:
Thus, if you want to hide the text and leave a blank space in its place, use `visibility: hidden`. If you want to hide the text and have it act as if it were not there at all, use `display: none`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to create a separate class for the text and set

```
visibility:hidden;
```

for that class.

Comment: Such a simple solution.  That works in IE7, IE8 and IE9. Thanks!